# Setting up Stable Diffusion in Google colab

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

Trying to setup Stable Diffusion on a notebook in Google Colab.

I keep getting errors when running it:

make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login`

```
    pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
      'CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4', revision='fp16',
      torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=True)
    pipe = pipe.to(device)
```

I have zero coding experience so not sure what to do from here as I have googled everything I could think of and have not found this issue elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Easy fix, do not put "make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. https://huggingface.co/spaces/stabilityai/stable-diffusion/discussions/12

It says `you probably did not visit https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4, read, accepted and acknowledged the LICENSE. If you do so, it should work!`